# Flutter PUT HTTP request from file

Tags: image, http, flutter, mobile, base64

Need some help troubleshooting an HTTP request in Flutter using the PUT method sending an image file on the body to a NextCloud server via API.

As always, i tested sending the request via POSTMAN to see what's happening. It worked ok selecting "binary" in the body tab and selecting the image file.

[image: Sending on postman]

The file is there as intended:

[image: Nextcloud server]

Moving to implement this on the Flutter app I'm using the code below:

_imageFile = Contains the image from camera or gallery.

```dart
RaisedButton(
  color: Colors.blueAccent,
  child: Text('enviar'),
  onPressed: () async {
    String base64Image = base64Encode(_imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
    print(base64Image);
    var client = http.Client();
    var request = http.Request(
        'PUT', Uri.parse('https://host123.com.br/remote.php/dav/files/82427565709/TOOP.jpeg'));
    request.headers.addAll(
        {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic ODI0Mjc1NjU3MDk6Y2xlYW5uZXQ=', 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
    request.body = base64Image;
var streamedResponse = await client.send(request);
    client.close();
    print('ok!');
  },
),
```

The result on terminal:

```
I/flutter ( 8349): 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
I/flutter ( 8349): ok
```

The result on the Nextcloud server sending via APP:

[image: Nextcloud server 2]

Looks like there is something wrong with the encoding or the data that's being sent on the body. The file get "corrupted"

It is the same file on both tests.

** UPDATE **

After changing the body data to just the bytes, as suggested, without base64encoding. (Image Below)

[image: Just bytes]

Tried convert using .toString() method too, the file went to the server but stayed the same as before, looking corrupted.

Comment: Why would you base 64 encode the body before sending it? Just send the bytes.

Comment: Hi @RichardHeap, changed the code as follows, but the "request.body" is expecting String datatype. Adding image to the original post.

Comment: Assign the bytes to `request.bodyBytes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to construct your own request, as the http package has a convenience `put` method. This method (and the more common `post` one) take an optional `body` parameter, which is a `dynamic`. If you pass bytes, these are sent verbatim. If you pass a string, it's encoded to bytes and sent. You can also pass a map of string to string which will be form encoded.

Your code can we simplified to:

```
  var uri = Uri.parse(
      'https://host123.com.br/remote.php/dav/files/82427565709/Lowppp.jpeg');
  var response = await http.put(
    uri,
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic xxxxxxx', // insert correct credentials here
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    },
    body: await _imageFile.readAsBytes(),
  );
  print(response.statusCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

@RichardHeap helped to find the solution.
It's needed to send the body as bytes, without converting and adding to the request as **bodyBytes** `request.bodyBytes = imageBytes;`

Full code working:

```dart
List<int> imageBytes = _imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
    var client = http.Client();
    var request = http.Request('PUT', Uri.parse('https://host123.com.br/remote.php/dav/files/82427565709/Lowppp.jpeg'));
    request.headers.addAll({HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic ODI0Mjc1NjU3MDk6Y2xlYW5uZXQ=', 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
    request.bodyBytes = imageBytes;
    var streamedResponse = await client.send(request).then((res) {
      print(res.statusCode);
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
    client.close();
```