# send a image via axios to nextcloud via api not working

Tags: react-native, image, axios, nextcloud

I need some help while try to upload a image in react native to my nextcloud.

My code is uploading a image.jpg but it is broken. It is the same issue like this in flutter:

[Flutter PUT HTTP request from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58529708/flutter-put-http-request-from-file)

My code to upload the file in binary (solution for the issue on top):

```
        const fileBytes = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(filePath);

        const response = await axios.put(networkSettings.serverUrl + '/' + 'filename' + '.jpg', fileBytes, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': networkSettings.authHeader,
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
            },
        });
```

But the image.jpg is < 1KB on my nextcloud. If I write the stream into a .txt file to the nextcloud I get only the first line of the binary stream.

Did someone has any idea?